# Exibir alerta em caso de nenhum registro encontrado - Ireport

Tags: php, javascript

Como fazer para o Ireport enviar apenas um alerta em caso de nenhum registro encontrado?

Atualmente, está com um

```
}else{

echo "Nenhum dado encontrado!!!";
```

então eu recebo uma página assim, gostaria de receber apenas um alerta, não abrir uma página, é possível?:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código completo:

```
/* begin page handling*/


                foreach ($this->arraydetail[$d] as $out) {
                    $this->currentrow=$this->arraysqltable[$this->global_pointer];

//                      echo $out["hidden_type"]."<br/>";
                    switch ($out["hidden_type"]) {
                        case "field":
                     //        $txt=$this->analyse_expression($compare["txt"]);
                       //  $out["txt"].":".print_r($out,true)."<br/>";
                 $maxheight=$this->detailallowtill-$checkpoint;//$this->arrayPageSetting["pageHeight"]-$this->arraypageFooter[0]["height"]-$this->pdf->GetY()+2-$this->columnheaderbandheight-$this->columnfooterbandheight;
                            $this->prepare_print_array=array("type"=>"MultiCell","width"=>$out["width"],"height"=>$out["height"],"txt"=>$out["txt"],
                                    "border"=>$out["border"],"align"=>$out["align"],"fill"=>$out["fill"],"hidden_type"=>$out["hidden_type"],
                                    "printWhenExpression"=>$out["printWhenExpression"],"soverflow"=>$out["soverflow"],"poverflow"=>$out["poverflow"],"link"=>$out["link"],
                                    "pattern"=>$out["pattern"],"writeHTML"=>$out["writeHTML"],"isPrintRepeatedValues"=>$out["isPrintRepeatedValues"],"valign"=>$out["valign"],
                                                                    "linktarget"=>$out['linktarget']);
                            $this->display($this->prepare_print_array,0,true,$maxheight);

              //                                  $checkpoint=$this->arraydetail[0]["y_axis"];

                            break;
                        case "relativebottomline":
                        //$this->relativebottomline($out,$tempY);
                            $this->relativebottomline($out,$biggestY);
                            break;
                          case "subreport":
                            $checkpoint=$this->display($out,$checkpoint);
                              //$this->arraydetail[0]["y_axis"]=$checkpoint;
                              //$biggestY=$checkpoint;
                              if($this->maxpagey['page_'.($this->pdf->getNumPages()-1)]<$checkpoint)
                              $this->maxpagey['page_'.($this->pdf->getNumPages()-1)]=$checkpoint;
                         break;
                        default:
                            //echo $out["hidden_type"]."=".print_r($out,true)."<br/><br/>";
                            $this->display($out,$checkpoint);
               $maxheight=$this->detailallowtill-$checkpoint;

                            //$checkpoint=$this->pdf->GetY();
                            break;
                    }

                    if($this->pdf->getNumPages()>1){

                    $this->pdf->setPage($currentpage);

                    }

                }
                //$this->pdf->lastPage();
                $checkpoint=$this->maxpagey['page_'.($this->pdf->getNumPages()-1)];


            }//end loop detail band[]
             $this->pdf->setPage($this->pdf->getNumPages());




                $this->global_pointer++;
                   $rownum++;           
                  $headerY=$checkpoint;      


            }


                    $this->global_pointer--;
        }else {

            echo "Nenhum dado encontrado!!!";


            // return ("http://facebook.com/");

            exit(0);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel acredito que seja assim

```
    if(empty($nome1) or empty($nome2)){

  echo "<script>alert('Nenhum campo pode fica vazio.');top.location.href='index.php' ;</script>";

}
```

[fonte](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/437700-resolvido%C2%A0campo-vazio/)

Comment: Não preciso verificar se o campo está vazio, mas o `echo` que colocou funcionou, a verificação é feita pelo próprio ireport, só precisava do alerta e retorno para a aplicação, Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não creio que seja tão simples, mas o que me vem na cabeça quando você pergunta isso é um simples

alert('Nenhum dado encontrado!!!');

não? Se não for isso (duvido que seja, honestamente), pode explicar melhor o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Vou adicionar o código completo

Comment: Mattheus Spoo, o alerta funciona, mas depois abre um página em branco